# Converting imblearn classification_report_imb() to csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, scikit-learn

I am trying to converting the **classification_report_imb** output to csv but cannot do it since it doesnt have the 'output_dict' function which the sklearn's classification_report does.

An example code is given below

```
class_report= classification_report_imbalanced(classifier_sample['is_fraud'],classifier_sample['is_fraud.1'])
class_report_imb = pd.DataFrame(class_report).transpose()
```

This code gives an error saying

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-121-6bd54fd818a9> in <module>()
     41 
     42     class_report= classification_report_imbalanced(classifier_sample['is_fraud'],classifier_sample['is_fraud.1'])
---> 43     class_report_imb = pd.DataFrame(class_report, output_dict=True).transpose()

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'output_dict'
```

Any solution or direction will be highly appreciated, thank you :).

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
from io import StringIO 

class_report_imb_csv = pd.read_csv(StringIO(re.sub(r'[-+|]', '', class_report)), sep='\s{2,}', engine='python')
```

This seemed to do the trick. Hope this helps someone in the future :)